# How to use "this.XXX" Class (component) properties in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, class, properties, components, state

Let me clarify a terminology what I say "Class Properties", I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
export default class ShowProperty extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.greeting = "Hello";   // <--- What I mentioned "Class Property" like this.
        this.state = {
            greeting2: "Fine, thank you"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

My questions are:

1. What is the correct name of this kind of variables?
2. What are the right time to use it?
3. Is it mutable?

The following code shows this property vs. State, both of it works fine:

```
import React from "react"

export default class ShowProperty extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.greeting = "Hello";
        this.state = {
            greeting2: "Fine, thank you"
        }
    }
    addExclaimationMark(){
        this.addExclaimationMarkForState();
        this.addExclaimationMarkForMember();
    }
    addExclaimationMarkForState(){
        this.setState({greeting2: this.state.greeting2 + "!!!"});
    }
    addExclaimationMarkForMember() {
        this.greeting = this.greeting + "!!!";
    }
    render() {
        const name = "John";
        return(
            <data>
                {this.greeting}, {name}<br/>
                {this.state.greeting2}
                <button onClick={()=>this.addExclaimationMark()}>
                    Add Exclaimation Mark
                </button>
            </data>
        );
    }
}
```

For the above code, I want to know what is the difference between "this.greeting" and "this.state.greeting2".

Thank you very much.

Comment: State is for values that change over time. When state changes, React knows it should re-render. If you change other class properties, React is out-of-the-loop so to speak and does not know it should re-render the component. If your values are not meant to change, then state is not the right place for them

Comment: So are the re-render just meant to be change UI only?